# Does Creating database in aws cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have tried to create a free tier postgres database in AWS. It shows estimation cost?

Estimated Monthly costs
DB instance
13.87 USD
Storage
2.40 USD
Total
16.27 USD
This billing estimate is based on on-demand usage as described in Amazon RDS Pricing . Estimate does not include costs for backup storage, IOs (if applicable), or data transfer.
Estimate your monthly costs for the DB Instance using the AWS Simple Monthly Calculator .

Is there payment for creating database?

Comment: Free tier for RDS is only available for the first year your AWS account exists. Check the specific details here to see if your database matches the free tier requirements https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RDS usage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/User_DBInstanceBilling.html) is billed in 1-second increments with a minimum of 10 minutes.

The estimate you quote assumes that the database runs continuously for a whole month.

If you create a database and immediately delete it, I think you would be charged something so close to zero it may be less than 1 cent.

As @Mark B points out, free-tier elegibility depends on how old the account is and whether the instance type meets the requirements. If you're not using db.t2.micro, db.t3.micro, and db.t4g.micro, you'll still get charged in a new account.